# Swift: OSX archive bit?

Tags: swift, macos, file, attributes, archive

Is there an archive bit I can use in OSX?
I want to copy some files and mark them as "processed". Therefor I need a marker. I like to use the archiv bit formerly used for backup files. How can I read /set it (if available)?

Comment: Use Extended Attributes on the file. Here's [a tutorial](http://nshipster.com/extended-file-attributes/)

Comment: And here is how to read/write extended attributes in Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343186/write-extend-file-attributes-swift-example.

Comment: Excellent. That's exactly what I need. Thank you