# Is there an API for com.apple.TextEncoding?

Tags: macos, encoding, nsurl, foundation, xattr

When you save an NSString (or Swift.String) using [a method like this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1417341-write), it writes the xattr "com.apple.TextEncoding".  When you load it back with one of the [corresponding methods](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1414472-init), it checks this xattr and uses that as the default encoding.

Is there any API to determine the encoding of a file, according to this xattr, without having to load the contents of the file?

I know it's not that hard to parse "IANA name, semicolon, CFString​Encoding uint32, (optional other stuff)", but I'd rather avoid it if there's a built-in way.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking for a way to read the value of the "com.apple.TextEncoding" extended file attribute. This is possible via API declared in `<sys/xattr.h>`.

Here's a post that extends `URL` with extended attributes capabilities:
[Write extend file attributes swift example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343186/write-extend-file-attributes-swift-example)

Example usage:

```
func getTextEncodingAttribute(for url: URL) -> String? {
    do {
        let data = try url.extendedAttribute(forName: "com.apple.TextEncoding")
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch _ {
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: That is how to read an xattr, yes, but it only gives the value as a String.  As I stated in the question, the icky part is *parsing this value*: the (overly complex) "IANA name ; CFStringEncoding, blah blah" format.