# Swift set some string value to file's attribute

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

According to Apple's document, we can set lots of attributes for a file

> A dictionary containing as keys the attributes to set for path and as values the corresponding value for the attribute. You can set the following attributes: busy, creationDate, extensionHidden, groupOwnerAccountID, groupOwnerAccountName, hfsCreatorCode, hfsTypeCode, immutable, modificationDate, ownerAccountID, ownerAccountName, posixPermissions. You can change single attributes or any combination of attributes; you need not specify keys for all attributes.

I want to set an extra parameter for a file. The parameter is a String, I can't find any attribute that I can set String. 
For example, I tried

```
try FileManager.default.setAttributes([FileAttributeKey.ownerAccountName: NSString(string: "0B2TwsHM7lBpSMU1tNXVfSEp0RGs"), FileAttributeKey.creationDate: date], ofItemAtPath: filePath.path)
```

But when I load keys

```
let keys = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath.path)
print(keys)
```

I only get .creationDate changed

```
[__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileType): NSFileTypeRegular,
__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFilePosixPermissions): 420,
__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileSystemNumber): 16777220,
__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileReferenceCount): 1,
__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName): staff,
__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileSystemFileNumber): 8423614,
__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID): 20,
__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileModificationDate): 2017-08-16 06:03:57 +0000, 
__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileCreationDate): 1970-01-01 00:33:20 +0000, 
__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileSize): 9795,
__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileExtensionHidden): 0,
__C.FileAttributeKey(_rawValue: NSFileOwnerAccountID): 501]
```

Is there any way that I can set string value to FileAttribute?

Comment: Perhaps a permission problem? Only the owner of a file (and root) can change the owner attribute.

Comment: no, but I've tried to use root user's account name as it, and also not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says "You can set the following attributes".  That means you can only set those specific attributes via those API's.

What you are really looking for are [Extended Attributes](http://nshipster.com/extended-file-attributes/), and these use a separate set of (C-style) API's.

Something like:

```
let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
let someExampleText = "some sample text goes here"
do {
    try someExampleText.write(toFile: "\(directory)/test.txt", atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
} catch let error {
    print("error while writing is \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
let valueString = "setting some value here"
let result = setxattr("\(directory)/test.txt", "com.stackoverflow.test", valueString, valueString.characters.count, 0, 0)

print("result is \(result) ; errno is \(errno)")
if errno != 0
{
    perror("could not save")
}

let sizeOfRetrievedValue = getxattr("\(directory)/test.txt", "com.stackoverflow.test", nil, 0, 0, 0)

var data = Data(count: sizeOfRetrievedValue)

let newResult = data.withUnsafeMutableBytes({
    getxattr("\(directory)/test.txt", "com.stackoverflow.test", $0, data.count, 0, 0)
})

if let resultString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
{
    print("retrieved string is \(resultString)")
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I advertently deleted my last comment. – Yes, that could be an invalid owner, or a permission problem.

Comment: yep... I deleted my comment after you deleted yours.  I was saying that the wacky userid string being passed in for `FileAttributeKey.ownerAccountName` does not look like a valid user id and so I'm thinking the OS is doing some validation and not allowing the change to happen to that attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I found one solution eventually. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343186/write-extend-file-attributes-swift-example

Comment: Yep.  I was trying to come up with a `getxattr` example and ended up googling up that same related answer as well.