# How does cString(using: .utf8) and withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation(_:) differ from each other?

Tags: c, swift, string, pointers

Consider the following code snippet:

```
let url = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser

let cString1 = url.absoluteString.cString(using: .utf8)

let cString2 = url.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { $0 }
```

Can we expect `cString1` and `cString2` to be equal C strings?

As described in the docs of [`withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779782-withunsafefilesystemrepresentati) it is converting the Swift string to a C string with UTF8 encoding. That's exactly the same as what [`cString(using: .utf8)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408489-cstring) is doing.

Both convert the Swift string to the type `UnsafePointer<Int8>?`.

Only Xcode is displaying the return type of `cString(using:)` as `[CChar]?` where [`CChar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cchar) is a type alias for `Int8`. Also a Swift array can just passed to an `UnsafePointer` as far as I know.

Mostly I just use `cString(using: .utf8)` and everything is fine but there are rare cases where I need to use `withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation(_:)` for some reason, otherwise the C function is not understanding the string.

So what is the difference I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Apple File System Guide FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html):

> To avoid introducing bugs in your code with mismatched Unicode normalization (for iOS 10.3.0, 10.3.1 and 10.3.2) in filenames, do the following:
>
> - Use high-level Foundation APIs such as NSFileManager and NSURL when interacting with the filesystem.
> - Use the fileSystemRepresentation property of NSURL objects when creating and opening files with lower-level filesystem APIs such as POSIX open(2), or when storing filenames externally from the filesystem.

So  `withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation()` is needed if the path
is passed to a POSIX call, such as `open()`, `stat()`, `unlink()`,
`getxattr()`, ... and guarantees that the correct Unicode
normalization form for the system call is created.

Simple example (remove file if it exists, ignoring errors):

```
url.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation {
    _ = unlink($0)
}
```

See [Write extend file attributes swift example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343186/write-extend-file-attributes-swift-example) for a "real" example. Note that

```
let cString2 = url.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { $0 }
```

is invalid because the C string is not valid outside the context of the block.

Here is an example demonstrating that the two APIs can give
different C strings:

```
let path = "Café".precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

path.withCString { s1 in
    url.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { s2 in
        print(strcmp(s1, s2) == 0) // false
    }
}
```

Using the Foundation APIs (`FileManager`, `URL`, ...) is recommended,
and then you don't have to care about the file system representation.