# Is there a way to access tags for files and folders in iOS?

Tags: ios, filesystems

I want to get a list of all tags and be able to get and set tags for files and folders in my iOS app's documents directory.
There is tags support in both the Files app in iOS and Finder in Mac OS, is there an API to access them in our own apps?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343186/write-extend-file-attributes-swift-example and use the `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags` extended attribute.

Comment: Is this attribute supposed to work on iOS? When i listExtendedAttributes  `com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags` was not one of them.