# Extra File Attributes Last Date Opened

Tags: swift, cocoa

Similar to Last Date Opened across different HD Formats ?

I've used the code in the link provided ...
[Write extend file attributes swift example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343186/write-extend-file-attributes-swift-example)

When listing Extended Attributes on Mac OS Extended Journaled I get "com.apple.lastuseddate#PS" which I can use but only on Mac OS, I tried FAT but didn't find anything similar attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Neither extended attributes nor a "last opened" time are universally supported across all filesystems, so I don't believe there's a consistent way to do this. However, you might have better luck with the "last access" time using `stat()` (in the `st_atime` field) or `getattrlist()` (by requesting `ATTR_CMN_ACCTIME`).

Comment: Thanks will look into it. I have found exFat does have this attribute.