# Save File with a custom property in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My app has a custom Document type and create, edit, and save the Documents with custom extension.  For saving I serialize the document and write `Data` to a file URL. For retrieving I use `FileManager` methods.

I want to save a custom value with File which I don't know how to do. I want to keep the File status as `editing` or `done`. When user create a new Document it's default status should be `editing` and he can make the file as `done` manually inside the app. I don't allow to edit `done` files , user can only view them.

Can I use `appendOnly: FileAttributeKey` for this purpose, assuming to make the file read-only if user marks it as done?

I also found this answer about extend file attributes [Write extend file attributes swift example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343186/write-extend-file-attributes-swift-example).
Is this a recommended way by Apple? If above attribute cannot help I guess I'll have to use extended file attributes.. please advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/fileattributekey/1414784-immutable

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks. But making immutable prevents from deleting the file? I want to delete `done` files too