# FileManager: Attribute for when a file was last opened

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager, file-attributes

I need a way of checking when a file was last opened. I tried by creating a custom FileAttributeKey and setting that to the current Date, but when I go to open the file again the attribute does not exist:

```
private let key = FileAttributeKey(rawValue: "lastOpenedAt")
do {
    try FileManager.default.setAttributes(
        [key: Date()],
        ofItemAtPath: videoNameDirectoryPath
    )
} catch {
    Log.error(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

So now I am resorting to using the modification date key to say when I last opened the file, it is not ideal so I am wondering if there is a better way to do this

Comment: Does `setAttributes` throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

setAttributes doesn't support custom attributes, you can only use the [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1413667-setattributes) ones.

To set your own attributes, you may use `xattr` as described in this question:

[Write extend file attributes swift example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343186/write-extend-file-attributes-swift-example)

If you're lucky, you may use `kMDItemLastUsedDate` from Spotlight aka `MDItem` as described in the documentation archive of [File Metadata Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreServices/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html).